# Why does Python 3 give a tab error when there seemingly is none?

Tags: python-3.x, tabs, indentation

I am writing a python game, and it says that there is an odd use of spaces and indentation. I do not know why, as it seems completely fine to me. Why is it not working?

```
import random
import time
from time import sleep
import sys

class Stats:
    def __init__(self, hunger, dehydration, phys_strength, mental_strength, psychic_powers, intelligence):
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.dehydration = dehydration
        self.phys_strength = phys_strength
        self.mental_strength = mental_strength
        self.psychic_powers = psychic_powers
        self.intelligence = intelligence

hero_stats = Stats(10, 10, 10, 20, 0, 20)

hunger_info = f"Your hunger level is {hero_stats.hunger}. Your stomach is full when you are at 0, and you starve at 100."


def user_input(input1):
    if input1.lower() == "hunger info":
        printfast("\n")
        printfast(hunger_info)
```

Error:

```
Python Files xxxxxxxxxxxxxx$ python3 adventuregame.py
  File "adventuregame.py", line 36
    printfast(hunger_info)
                         ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
xxxxxxx-Air:Python Files xxxxxxxxxxxxxx$
```

Comment: the error message means you have mixed tabs and spaces. search for all tabs and replace them with spaces (or the other way round - as you prefer), but do not mix them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tab just before `printfast("\n")` on the previous line, while the rest of the indentation has been done with spaces.

You should always use an editor that converts tabs to 4 spaces.